# Find the nearest point for each point in dataframe

Tags: python, coordinates, nearest-neighbor, geopy

I have a dataframe with ID, Latitude and Longitude:

```
ID  Latitude   Longitude        coords
A    45.0353    52.5362   (45.0353, 52.5362)
B    24.6374    12.5363   (24.6374, 12.5363)
C    42.3539    21.O530   (42.3539, 21.O530)
D    48.3638    18.3903   (48.3638, 18.3903)
```

And I need for every of them, find the nearest one and the distance would be the fifth column in desired dataframe. I try with:

```
dicts1 = dict(zip(df.ID, df.coords))
dicts2 = dict(zip(df.ID, df.coords))

f_dict={}
for key, value in dicts1.iteritems():
    for k, v in dicts2.iteritems():
        lista.append(geopy.distance.vincenty(value, v).km)
        f_dict.update({key:lista})
```

I got just the one distance for all of them, but at this moment I need to get len(data['ID']) number of value for each of them, and that's about 1500, so 1500*1500, after that I need to take nearest, lowest distance(except 0). So, something is wrong and I can't figure it out how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't shown how `lista` is defined. If you place `lista=[]` at the start of the outer for-loop then it will give you the 1500*1500 set of values that you are looking for. However note that you don't need to define the dictionaries twice; rather you can iterate over the same dictionary twice. Further, you can update `f_dict` after the inner loop completes rather than update it within each iteration:

```
dicts = dict(zip(df.ID, df.coords))

f_dict={}
for key, value in dicts.iteritems():
    lista = []
    for k, v in dicts.iteritems():
        lista.append(geopy.distance.vincenty(value, v).km)
    f_dict.update({key:lista})
```

You would then have to iterate over `f_dict` to get the minimums that you want.

However note that calculating geographic distances can be computationally slow and so you could try ignore repeating pairs. That is, if you've already done `A` and `B` then you don't need to calculate it for `B` and `A`. Here is a version of the code that avoids duplicated calculation and returns the dictionary with the minimum distances directly:

```
dicts = dict(zip(df.ID, df.coords))
f_dict={}

def update_distances(keys, distance):
    for k in keys:
        try:
            if distance < f_dict[k]:
                f_dict.update({k:distance})
        except KeyError:
            f_dict.update({k:distance})

for idx1, (key, value) in enumerate(dicts.iteritems()):
    for idx2, (k, v) in enumerate(dicts.iteritems()):
        if idx2 <= idx1:
            continue # Skip a repeated calculation of distance
        update_distances([key, k], geopy.distance.vincenty(value, v).km)
```